# Zabbix 3.4 and Nginx admin login fail (only guest)

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, zabbix

Incoming - LEMP (Ubuntu 16.04/Nginx/PHP7.0/MySQL)

I am novice here and need your help

I have a question about a connection to Zabbix admin page after setup that with Nginx. After successful setup Zabbix server, I receive the page from the link below

http://prntscr.com/glp8yg

I think the problem is with the Nginx setup

Could you please help me with the right Nginx code? I am novice in Nginx

my Nginx /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/zabbix configuration you can find below

```
    server {listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name MY_SERVER_IP;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/my_cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/my_key.key;
    root /usr/share/zabbix;
    index index.php index.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$args;
    }}
```

Please help me I am novice in

SOLVED: I changed the parameter cgi.fix_pathinfo= from 0 to 1 in /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini then restarted php and it works fine now

Comment: Can you try clicking 'Log In' and using the default zabbix login? Not 100% sure, but I think it's 'admin' and 'zabbix'. I don't think it's an issue with Nginx

Comment: Clicking 'Login' do nothing (return me at the same page)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try User:Admin Password:zabbix with the browser chrome and firefox.

NB: Not use Internet Explorer browser. user:Admin not user:admin.

Comment: Page at the link above after the click on "Login" return that page again


"Go to Dashboard" login me with the guest rights


If I try to logoff that page appears again


Also I know about letters in login as admin


also I know about user privileges at DB

I can't see the authentication window below


http://prntscr.com/gltbg9


Just only


http://prntscr.com/glp8yg

And I don't use IE, only Safari, and clear a cache after regular attempts